# Why there are some black lines in gradient image?

Tags: display, images, colors, gradient

I have tried some ways to test the gradient image such as look at the gradient testing website, for example http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/gradient.php and https://www.eizo.be/monitor-test/, use html + css to create gradient background, also look at some gradient images. I found that there are some black lines appear.

I have tried to use python with pillow library to create jpg file with gradient, and I have took some pictures of what I see.

[jpg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2giZ.jpg)

Code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw 
im = Image.open("in.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.rectangle((0, 0, 256, 256), fill=(256, 256, 256))
for i in range(0, 256):
    draw.rectangle((i, 0, i+1, 256), fill=(i, i, i))
del draw
im.save("in.jpg")
```

See on iphone 11 (screenshot):
[iphone 11 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzvNQ.jpg)

See on vg259q monitor using intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (taken by iphone 11): [vg259q photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgMvH.jpg)

It seems not the problem with color depth because the black lines are darker than two sides of them.
I want to know is this problem appear to all gradient images, all displays and all processors?

Comment: No banding on my monitor - you certainly have a hardware problem. The only question is whether the problem is in your monitor or video card. Trying another monitor will give the answer to this problem.

Comment: I have tested with another monitor HP24ea and another computer with AMD Radeon R5 M435 and have the same problem. May I know what monitor and video card are you using? Thank you.

Comment: My setup doesn't matter, but are you getting these problems with the above websites or with your program or both?

Comment: I am getting these problems with both the websites and my program.

Comment: On two computers and two monitors in all combinations? In that case look for a common cause, for example a bad video cable or strong magnetic fields (unlikely).

Comment: My guess is either JPEG compression artifact or resizing artifact (plus maybe optical illusion?) –What is the default JPEG quality level in PIL and does this change if you save at a higher quality or even as a PNG file? And have you tried making a larger original image so that it won't need to be upscaled when viewing?

Comment: I didn't try all the combinations of monitors and computers. According to https://jdhao.github.io/2019/07/20/pil_jpeg_image_quality/ , the quality of PIL is not the highest by default. I will try the tests and give the answers tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: I also get a smooth gradient (so much as 8 bit per channel can be smooth)  with no out-of-place black bands

Comment: Try creating a PNG file instead of a JPG file.

Comment: have tried all the combinations of monitors and computers in my home and also switched the cables, all combinations results with the black lines appear. I also tried to create png file using the code
import png
col = []
for i in range(256):
    for j in range(12):
        col.append(i)
row = []
for i in range(1024):
    row.append(col)
f = open('swatch.png', 'wb')
w = png.Writer(1024, 1024, greyscale=False)
w.write(f, row)
f.close()

and the black lines still appear.

Comment: However you guys didn't see the black lines, so it shouldn't be the problem with the method I used for testing. I guess I can not figure out what cause the problem until I have a new computer. Thank you for you guys' reply.